# Facebook tab app page is blank! what am I missing?

Tags: facebook-iframe

I have created a 520 px page for FB. I have gone through all of the developers steps. I can see the page from the link. i can see the page from the secure link. copying all of the links from the FB app, they work. I have set up the tab and I see the tab on my FB page. When i click the tab or go directly to the tab, FB is there but it is just white space. I can't see what I am missing. I have loaded, reloaded, cleared cache, etc. I'm sure it's something simple, but I've spent hours searching. thanks.

Comment: I struggled with this problem for a while, and finally found a solution. Please see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304528/facebook-page-tab-is-empty-even-for-google-com/11307918#11307918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. I put the secure address in the non also and took out the "s". for some reason linking to the page from the "normal" address didn't work. I use a shared cert. I think FB checks secure first or something.Really a stupid thing. It was all set up correctly. Who would think that you had to alter the non

Comment: Hey @David, I'm having difficulty understanding your solution - I think there are some missing words and thoughts. Would you mind editing it for clarity? I'm having a similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: He had the HTTPS url entered in both fields; the page tab URL and secure page tab URL - this isn't supported - you must have both a HTTP and HTTPS URL

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a bad SSL cert.  Ensure it is not one of those dummy/fake certs that you get for free.

Comment: No, the cert was fine. I got it to work. I put the secure address in the non also and took out the "s". for some reason linking to the page from the "normal" address didn't work. I use a shared cert. I think FB checks secure first or something.Really a stupid thing. It was all set up correctly. Who would think that you had to alter the non secure address.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer to the specific issue the OP had, but I had the exact same symptoms and the solution for me was to *disable AdBlock*.  Facebook uses a number of nested iframes and proxies to load your app and my AdBlock was blocking the content.